# In the proof that in a PID, every non-zero non-unit is the product of irreducibles...

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

In proving that all non-zero non-units of a PID are a product of irreducibles, theres:

> "We now show that $a$ is a product of irreducibles. If $a$ is irreducible,
>   we are done. Otherwise let $p_1$ be an irreducible such that $p_1|a$. Then
>   $a=p_1c_1$. If $c_1$ is a unit, we are done. "

How did they get that they're done?

I've got $aR = p_1 c_1 R = p_1 R$ if $c_1$ is a unit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c_1$ is a unit, then $a=p_1c_1$ is in fact irreducible. Since we assumed that was not the case, then $c_1$ is not a unit.

I suspect that what they meant to say is "If $c_1$ is *irreducible*, we are done."

Comment: How do you prove that $p_1c_1$ is irreducible?

Comment: What is your definition of irreducible? The proof will depend on that.

Comment: A non-zero non-unit that cannot be written as the product of two non-units

Comment: In that case, we can proceed as follows. Suppose that $a=p_1c_1,$ where $p_1$ is irreducible and $c_1$ is a unit. Since $a$ is non-zero, non-unit, and reducible, then there exist non-unit $b,c$ such that $a=bc.$ But then $$p_1=ac_1^{-1}=bcc_1^{-1}=b(cc_1^{-1}),$$ so since $p_1$ is irreducible, then one of $b,cc_1^{-1}$ has to be a unit. We assumed that $b$ was not, so $cc_1^{-1}$ is a unit--call it $u$--whence $c=uc_1.$ But then $c$ is a product of units, so again a unit, which we supposed it was not. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll write the result down in my notes :)

Comment: No problem. More generally, if $x$ is (zero/a unit/irreducible/reducible) and $u$ is a unit, then $ux$ and $xu$ are likewise (zero/units/irreducible/reducible).